# R count number of variables with value ="mq" per row

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 70variables, I want to create a new variable which counts the number of occurrences where the 70 variables take the value "mq" on a per row basis.

I am looking for something like this:

```
[ID] [Var1] [Var2] [Count_mq]
1.    mq    mq      2
2.    1     mq      1
3.    1      7      0
```

I have found this solution:

count_row_if("mq",DT)

But it gives me a vector with those values for the whole data frame and it is quite slow to compute.

I would like to find a solution using the function apply() but I don't know how to achieve this.

Best.

Comment: Try `rowSums(DT == "mq")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'apply' function to count a particular value in your existing dataframe 'df',

```
df$count.MQ <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(x=="mq")))
```

Here the second argument is 1 since you want to count for each row. You can read more about it from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/apply

Answer (score 0):

I assume the name of dataset is DT. I'm a bit confused what you really want to get but this is how I understand. Data frame consists of 70 columns and a number of rows that some of them have observations 'mq'.
If I get it right, please see the code below.

```
apply(DT, function(x) length(filter(DT,value=='mq')), MARGIN=1)
```